# Redux Fetch JSON Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

my Redux fetch is returning empty..
It does not break but it just returns me empty object.

Here is the code for my action (newsActions.js):

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import kickstarterData from '../server/kickstarter-october.json';

export const FETCH_KICKSTARTER = 'FETCH_KICKSTARTER';

export function fetchKickstarter() {

 return {
  type: FETCH_KICKSTARTER,
  payload: {
   data: kickstarterData
  }
 };
}
```

Here is my Reducer:

```js
import { FETCH_KICKSTARTER } from '../actions/kickstarterActions';


export default function(state = [], action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_KICKSTARTER:
   debugger;
   return [action.payload.data, ...state];
 }

 return state;
};
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Here is my index.js that combines all the reducers:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NewsReducer from './reducer_news';
import KickstarterReducer from './reducer_kickstarter';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  news: NewsReducer,
  kickstarters: KickstarterReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Finally, inside my app.js I have the following code:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    news: state.news,
    kickstarters: state.kickstarters
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {...newsActions, ...kickstarterActions})(App);
```

Could anyone tell me why this is breaking?
Also, could anyone suggest me a better/cleaner way of writing these codes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that in your reducer

`return [action.payload.data, ...state];`

should be

`return [...action.payload.data, ...state];`

Frankly it should be just

`return [...action.payload.data ];`

Since i don't have any idea about your biz logic, but later seems more correct to me *(why do you need to merge it with old state)*.

you need to spread the `action.payload.data` in the state.